# Creating geodatabase administrator account other than SDE?

Tags: postgresql, enterprise-geodatabase, esri-geodatabase, security

I need to create another account other than SDE and make it geodatabase administrator. Is it possible?

I have already created another account and have given SUPERUSER priviledge. However I cannot do GDB admin tasks like database compression.

Do I have to change ArcSDE system tables too?

I am working with PostreSQL RDBMS.

Comment: There can only be **one**  SDE user in an Oracle enterprise geodatabase.  What you seek is not possible.

Comment: What about postgresql? Is it documented anywhere?

Comment: Of all the RDBMS, only SQL_Server allows DBO to own SDE tables (and doing so seriously messes with the security model).

Comment: @Vince, If a user has the proper privileges, how is it not possible?  Can you describe why?!  Do you mean its part of system design?!

Comment: You cannot have the proper privileges, since you must be SDE.

Comment: I think what you need is privileges http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//002n0000002t000000 if you can't do these operations your account lacks UPDATE permission perhaps. There's a whole discourse on user/group roles and privileges https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/manage-data/gdbs-in-postgresql/privileges-postgresql.htm does that help? You don't *need* to be SDE you just need the same abilities. There was also something about each login needs it's own tablespace in the public schema to hold intermediates but I can't remember where I read that.

Comment: @Michael you are contradicting Vince, and I think Vince is right here. I have given all the permissions ,including UPDATE, to a user and even made him SUPERUSER but to no avail! Can you share a SQL block to create second gdb admin user?

Comment: The privileges are not on the PostgreSQL end they are on the Esri end... I'm sure I don't understand why Esri needs the permissions set on that end but there has to be a good reason for it. I found when I was working with users/roles/permissions it was best not to do much on the SQL end as it had no effect on abilities in ArcCatalog. I don't think I'm contradicting Vince; you use SDE login to create the database, assign full priveleges to admin login/role for that database then use an admin  to connect ArcCatalog and create the feature classes *then* your admin can compact the database.

Comment: How am I supposed to "assign full priveleges to admin login/role for that database" in ArcCatalog !!!!?  You are contradicting Vince, because Vince believes "What I seek is not possible"

Answer (score 1):

From what I can tell, it depends on if you used SDE or DBO database schema to set up the database.  If you look at the table at https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/manage-data/gdbs-in-sql-server/comparison-geodatabase-owners-sqlserver.htm  it explains that if you use the DBO schema, it is basically having the RDBMS system admin or the database admin own all the SDE tables.  Therefore, anyone mapped to the system/database admin role would be able to perform GDB maintenance activities like you bring up.  However, if you are using the SDE schema, those SDE tables are owned by the single user mapped to SDE, meaning only a single user can be granted these administrative permissions.

However, the other thing to remember is, if you have the SDE schema, you do not necessarily have to have someone use SDE user as their daily user to perform these admin type actions.  You could save a *.sde GDB connection file to a folder/network location that only designated people can get to.  Then have anyone who needs to, use that connection file to perform admin type actions.  Now, please not, THIS MAY BE A SIGNIFICANT SECURITY RISK, depending on how your system/network security is set up, the individuals in your organization, and the specifics of how you choose to implement it.  But, I bring it up because switching everything over to the DBO schema just so you can give more users super user access to your GDB may be just as much of a risk, again depending on many of the same factors.

Comment: John, thank for the answer. Have you noticed postgresql tag in my question? we are not dealing with SQL Server.